# Необходима ли запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Люди Анвила неопрятны и скучны, за исключением, конечно, знаменитой писательницы-аргонианки Куилл-Вив, сочинившей множество безвкусных книжек о жизни преступников и простолюдинов. Многие считают, что аргониане сплошь безбожники, лжецы и ничтожества, что они лишь немногим лучше диких зверей(,) — и предприимчивая писательница является прекрасной илллюстрацией данного расхожего мнения.

Необходима ли запятая в указанном месте?

Анвил – город, аргониане – раса полуящеров-полулюдей из одной серии фэнтезийных компьютерных игр. Предложение взято из книги, написанной от лица персонажа ([полная версия](https://tes.ag.ru/oblivion/books/Book1CheapGuideAnvil.shtml.html)). Этот и другие тексты переведены с английского, иногда в них встречаются ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Многие считают, что аргониане сплошь безбожники, лжецы и ничтожества, что они лишь немногим лучше диких зверей, — и предприимчивая писательница является прекрасной иллюстрацией данного расхожего мнения.*

Здесь ставится запятая и тире **как единый знак**.

Пояснение

**1. Запятая и  тире как единый знак**

Единый знак – интересный знак препинания, еще не полностью изученный, но достаточно распространенный, то есть необходимый в определенных ситуациях.

У него особая **интонационная характеристика** – это не просто увеличение паузы, а **разделительный знак**, обозначающий четкое деление предложения на две части. Розенталь в этом случае говорит о **переломе и структурном повороте** конструкции.

Даже в ПАС под ред. Лопатина (там интонации уделяется обычно мало внимания) говорится о произношении **с повышением тона,**  значительно  увеличенной паузой и **последующим понижением тона**. У двоеточия и обычного разделительного тире немного другая интонационная характеристика, они не могут заменить этот знак.

**2. Чем можно объяснить необходимость единого знака в данном случае?**

Первая часть – это СПП с однородными придаточными и однородными членами (**значительное распространение, собственные знаки**), ее важно четко отделить от второй части, то есть обозначить расчлененность и структурный поворот.

Также между двумя частями мы видим **смысловое соответствие**, поэтому нам нужно **противопоставить** эти части (а это именно разделительная интонация, она, к примеру, используется В БСП при противопоставлении).

Ни запятая, ни тире по отдельности эту задачу  не могут выполнить, поэтому используется единый знак.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (для тех, кому интересен интонационный анализ и выводы из него)

Что можно сказать по поводу поводу **АВТОРСКОГО ЗНАКА**?  Я считаю, что это не авторский знак, так что пора повысить его статус. Просто теория этого вопроса не проработана до конца, вот он и **кажется авторским.**

В действительности он вполне **логично  дополняет систему** из  4-х знаков: с одной стороны это (1) разделительное и присоединительное тире, а с другой –  (2) единый знак и двоеточие.

Внутри групп знаки различаются по **виду интонации** (разделительная или присоединительно-пояснительная), а между группами различие делается по **длительности** пауз (в первой группе пауза короче, чем во второй).

Дополнение **(о наращениях)**

Я, конечно, всегда подчиняюсь законам (не требуется, так не требуется), но мне такая графика кажется **некрасивой**. Народ тоже упорно пишет с наращением, а Грамота.ру так же последовательно истребляет  «ересь».

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=4-х](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=4-%D1%85)

Comment: Извините, _Sharon_, но я ничего не понимаю в Вашем дополнении.  _В действительности он вполне логично дополняет систему из 4-х знаков..._ Какую систему их четырех знаков? (Наращение, думаю, не нужно.) _...с одной стороны это (1) разделительное и присоединительное тире, а с другой – (2) единый знак и двоеточие._ Где же в ответе отмечены (1) и (2)? О каком двоеточии Вы говорите? Внутри каких групп знаки различаются?

Comment: Римма, спасибо за замечания, я отвечу на ваш комментарий отдельно, в поле ответа.  Здесь же скажу следующее. Информация о едином знаке  дана  как ОТДЕЛЬНАЯ ТЕМА, но в этом предложении  удобно ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ именно этот знак. Почему? Нам нужна разделительная интонация и значительно увеличенная  пауза, как при двоеточии, а это УСЛОВИЯ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ единого знака. Поэтому его надо применять по существу, а не по отдельным ПУНКТАМ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно предположить следующие варианты пунктуации.

1. Однородные придаточные предложения.
   Многие считают, **что** аргониане сплошь безбожники, лжецы и ничтожества, **что** они лишь немногим лучше диких зверей **и что** предприимчивая писательница...
2. Запятая закрывает придаточное.
   Многие считают, что аргониане сплошь безбожники, лжецы и ничтожества, **что они лишь немногим лучше диких зверей, и** предприимчивая писательница...
3. Запятая закрывает придаточное + авторское интонационное тире — для смыслового разграничения предложения (при наличии предыдущих четырех запятых).
   Многие считают, что аргониане сплошь безбожники, лжецы и ничтожества, **что они лишь немногим лучше диких зверей, — и** предприимчивая писательница...

Так что запятая, конечно же, нужна.
Текст, к сожалению, не является пунктуационно грамотным. Ошибки навскидку:
*Столица графства Анвил располагается на берегу моря, и на первый взгляд может показаться чудеснейшим местом в Тамриэле* (запятая перед "и" не нужна);
*Портовый район располагается за южными стенами города, и соединяется с ним воротами западного района* (запятая перед "и" не нужна);
*Единственное, ради чего стоит заглянуть в портовый район — это весьма симпатичный маяк, с площадки которого открывается отличный вид на гавань, море и город* (нужна запятая после слова "район").

Comment: Спасибо. Запятая закрывает придаточное. Английский текст можно посмотреть, кликнув по "English version" справа вверху. Вот предложение, про которое я спрашиваю: This person does her race no favor by confirming the prejudices of many who consider Argonians to be ungodly, dishonest, and worthless, and little better than beasts.

Comment: М-м... Это я погорячилась — по поводу контекста (столько английского у меня нет). Но смысл моего ответа от этого не изменяется: запятая необходима. Вообще-то вопрос можно было сформулировать и по-другому: нужно ли тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на комментарий

**Запятая и тире как единый знак**

Ну что вы, Римма, это очень даже извинительно, я ведь и пометку сделала: читать тем, кому интересен способ ИНТОНАЦИОННОГО АНАЛИЗА. Очень немногие хотят его освоить. Хотя  в модели он несложный, но здесь важна практика, нужно постоянно тренироваться (хотя бы на наших вопросах на форуме).

Возможно, вы говорите с иронией. Если же нет, то я с удовольствием дам пояснение и вам, и всем желающим понять тему.

1. **О «системе знаков»**

Это чисто условное название. Присмотримся к ***единому знаку***. Розенталь говорит о нем в теме бессоюзных и сложноподчиненных предложений, причем можно сделать такой вывод: практика применения этого знака достаточно широка,  да и в реальных текстах он встречается часто.

В то же время нет пока четкого понимания его смысла, его назначения. Иногда единый знак  называют **авторским**, иногда **устаревающим**. Я думаю, что неверно ни то, ни другое.

2. Наши знаки препинания удобно **связать с интонацией**

**У двоеточия** четкая интонация: неполное понижение голоса перед  значительно увеличенной  паузой (информация из учебника, также интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю).

А вот тире у нас два (**разделительное и присоединительное**), хотя редко кто скажет об этом. Почему такое деление? Потому что интонация совершенно **разная:**  после первой части при  разделительной интонации  мы **повышаем** голос, а при  присоединительной – **понижаем**. На слух различается четко.

3. А  если нам нужна **разделительная интонация со значительно увеличенной паузой**?  Такая интонация действительно существует, и это как функция единого знака: переход от повышения к понижению (даже по Лопатину!) и особая  пауза – предупредительная, подчеркнутая, как у двоеточия.
4. **Вот пары и построены**: (1) разделительное и присоединительное тире и (2) разделительный единый знак и пояснительное  двоеточие.

Во второй паре мы видим одинаковую по длительности **паузу** (интонационное предупреждение), но разную характеристику по **движению тона** в первой части  (повышение или понижение). **Полная симметрия!**

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (здравствуй, единый знак!)

Переведи меня через майдан, —

***Он битвами, слезами, смехом дышит,***

***Порой меня и сам себя не слышит.***

*Переведи меня через майдан.*

Виталий Коротич в переводе Юнны Мориц

Философское стихотворение: наша жизнь среди людей, наши успехи неудачи. Полный текст:   https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Rjts/kxUiMPsoT