# Чем объяснить отсутствие обособления "как всегда"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова

***...Эта женщина вошла в комнату и в… мою жизнь”, – как всегда тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.***

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить отсутствие запятых вокруг "как всегда"? Конечно, запятую тут ну никак ставить не хочется, но как можно это объяснить? Прав ли я, что в данном случае "как всегда" является наречным выражением и потому не обособляется?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, думаю, что он интересный и нестандартный. Будем надеяться на интересные ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой теме можно выделить **две интересные особенности**:  (1) прямая речь со значительным распространением; (2) отличие наречных сочетаний от вводных слов в парных вариантах.

1. **Прямая речь со значительным распространением**

Полная цитата выглядит так:

*"Легко объяснить, почему не любишь, и невозможно объяснить, почему любишь. Тут есть вещи очень личные, даже, пожалуй, интимные. Почему после 37 лет совместной жизни я вот так круто все сломал. За год до этого просто рассмеялся бы в лицо человеку, который сказал бы, что такое может произойти со мной. Когда люди живут вместе долго, они либо становятся все ближе, либо в какой-то момент понимают, что что-то не так. В большинстве случаев они с этим мирятся. И мне казалось, что я примирился, хотя это на меня и не похоже. Но, видимо, только казалось. **Эта женщина вошла в комнату и в… мою жизнь", – как всегда тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.***

Распространенные варианты прямой речи встречаются часто при анализе стихотворений. В большинстве случаев цитирование оформляется в виде прямой речи по схеме А – П, но возможны и другие схемы оформления (схема П – А):

*Не жалею, не зову, не плачу.

Всё пройдёт, как с белых яблонь дым.

Увяданья золотом охваченный,

Я не буду больше молодым, –

**так С. Есенин раскрывает** тему вечного потока жизни, тему изменения и обновления.*

Мы привыкли к такому оформлению прямой речи, но давайте попробуем взглянуть на нее **особым способом** – как это выглядит с точки зрения **обычного синтаксиса**.

Предложение с прямой речью похоже на БСП, только высказывание в первой части выделено (кавычками или расположением в абзац), а вместо тире используется **единый знак** – запятая и тире, обозначающий деление предложения на две части  (**структурный поворот**). Примечание. Обсуждение единого знака можно посмотреть в теме: "[Необходима ли запятая перед тире](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464404/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5)".

Можно сравнить с оформлением  БСП:

*Он рассуждал **так**: отцу раньше шутя можно было прожить* (указательное местоимение ТАК в первой части).

*Потерять Москву или потерять армию – **так** стоял вопрос перед Кутузовым* (указательное местоимение ТАК во второй части).

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**. В то же время при использовании в прямой речи единый знак (запятая и тире) имеет определенные **фонетические** особенности – он в большей степени напоминает обычное **присоединительное** тире (с понижением, а не с повышением тона и более короткой паузой).  Другими словами на первое место здесь ставится способность единого знака делить конструкцию **на две части**, а не его фонетика.

Слова автора действительно часто выглядят как **присоединение** – недаром при упрощенном оформлении  дословного выказывания может использоваться **вводное** предложение с обособлением запятой. Но  слова автора  могут быть и **распространенными** тоже, однако в любом случае **обособление** внутри это  конструкции нежелательно.  Иначе мы получаем как бы «**третий план**" речи – ведь и само присоединение  трактуется как добавочное сообщение  на уровне «вставки».

**Для чего нам всё это нужно?** Приведенная информация поможет понять, почему «как всегда» является здесь **наречием**, а не вводным словом.

2. **Отличие наречных сочетаний от вводных слов в парных вариантах.**

Вот наш участник пишет: "В некоторых предложениях трудно определить, обстоятельство это (наречное выражение со значением как обычно) или вводное слово". Неужели семантика сочетания **меняется** при обособлении –  было вводное слово "как всегда", а стало наречие "как обычно"?

Вот и **Справочник по пунктуации** нам говорит об этом, но только **лукавыми** кажутся мне эти слова. Впрочем, Справочник вообще не так уж точен в своей информации – уж слишком часто практика письма **противоречит** сказанному там (не очень-то я ему доверяю).

Тема вводных слов всегда сложна для пользователей, и, как мне кажется, там очень не хватает такого понимания: **семантика** в парных вариантах «вводное слово – наречие» меняется не так часто, а вот обособление  наречного выражения (в функции вводного слова) зависит в большей степени **от структуры** предложения, а не от семантики.

Структуру выбирает **автор** (с учетом семантики тоже), нам же предлагается уже готовая структура, которую и нужно как раз анализировать.

В *Справочнике по пунктуации* дается **минимум информации**:  сочетание ***как всегда*** не обособляется в составе именного сказуемого. В других учебных материалах добавляется следующее: или при **тесной связи со сказуемым**.

А вот это требует **расшифровки**. Наречие образует словосочетания (связь управление) с глаголом, с прилагательным и с другим наречием (очень тесная связь), и примеров тому (в художественной литературе) можно найти **множество.** [Предложения со словосочетанием «как всегда»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Мы же отдельно рассмотрим **слова автора.**

(1) *Как всегда тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер*. Также возможно: *Всегда тонко и красноречиво описывает свои чувства Владимир Познер.*  Здесь наречие относится **к другому наречию** –  к паре (тонко и красноречиво).

(2) *Как всегда, тонко и красноречиво, описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.*  Здесь два наречия (причем второе со значением уточнения) относятся **к глаголу**.

(3) *Как всегдА, тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер*.
Это уже функция **вводного слова**, сочетание обособляется. Но этот вариант **нежелательно** использовать в схеме П – А.

Но, может быть, вам так **НЕ КАЖЕТСЯ**, уважаемые участники форума, участвующие в голосовании против моего ответа (не автор вопроса, нет, я это хорошо вижу)? Тогда попробуйте прочитать эту фразу как **отдельное предложение**: *Как всегдА, тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.* С точки зрения  **фонетики** звучит вполне нормально, нет вопросов, то есть такое предложение прочитать можно, а вот **смысл** в нем какой?

Если персонаж описывает свои чувства, то делает это тонко и красноречиво, но это ли имел в виду автор? Возможно,  он хотел сказать о том, что наш герой **в своих рассуждениях** всегда тонок и красноречив. Но о смысле **сложно спорить**, поэтому желательно использовать решение автора (нет запятой).

Что касается приведенного варианта предложения, то для **распространенной прямой речи перед словами автора**, где очень важно обозначить деление текста НА ДВЕ ЧАСТИ, этот вариант вообще не подойдет (уже с точки зрения фонетики).

3. **А теперь совместим две темы: что же нам подходит?**

К схеме П – А  более всего подходит вариант (1), так как любое обособление  плохо вписывается в **двухчастную** конструкцию с запятой и тире.

Comment: Хочу все-таки поблагодарить  автора правки, хотя и обещала ему не надоедать со своей благодарностью.  Просто неловко, что вам приходится тратить свое время. Но обещаю, что таких длинных ответов больше писать не буду.  По возможности... Вот честное слово :)

Comment: А вам спасибо за спасибо! Сначала хочу поправить несколько опечаток, потом втягиваюсь в оформление. Ну уж если берусь править, значит, располагаю временем. Пишите, сколько душе угодно!

Answer (score 2):

*Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объяснить отсутствие запятых вокруг "как всегда"?*
Думаю, что правильно вопрос должен быть сформулирован так: как объяснить отсутствие запятой **после** "как всегда"? (Двух запятых тут быть не может.)

В начале неполной цитаты тоже необходимы кавычки, а для обозначения пропуска можно воспользоваться угловыми скобками, так как в [цитируемом тексте](https://pozneronline.ru/2015/12/13662/) уже есть многоточие:
***«<...>** Эта женщина вошла в комнату и в... мою жизнь».*

*Как всегда тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер* — это отдельное предложение (слова автора), в котором нет никаких обособленных оборотов, а "как всегда" находится в начале этого предложения.
В некоторых предложениях трудно определить, обстоятельство это (наречное выражение со значением *как обычно*) или вводное слово. Здесь же, мне кажется, такой пунктуацией автор хотел показать, что "как всегда" относится только к наречию "тонко" (смысл: в рассказах о своей личной жизни Познер *всегда тонок*, но сегодня еще и красноречив).

Answer (score 1):

**Автореферат к первому ответу**

1. Действительно, в приведенном высказывании  «как всегда» не обособляется, так как является **наречным выражением** в роли обстоятельства, а не вводным словом.
2. Различение подобных пар – наиболее трудная тема в русской пунктуации. Традиционно считается,  что **разную семантику**  для пары можно определить заранее, но это не совсем так.  «Как всегда» или «как обычно» – нет разницы. Условно можно сказать, что  во многих случаях вводное слово – это **обособленное наречное выражение.**
3. Для заданной пары (вводное слово – наречное выражение) семантика не меняется, но **смысл всего предложения** может зависеть от обособления наречного сочетания. Вводное слово (оценка автора) обычно относится ко всему предложению, а наречные выражения – к отдельным словам. В частности наречие образует словосочетания (связь примыкание) с глаголом, прилагательным или другим наречием, и внутри предложения эти связи сохраняются.
4. Поэтому рассмотрим слова автора отдельно и составим **возможные структурные варианты:**

(1) *Как всегда тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.*  Здесь наречие относится к другому наречию – к паре (тонко и красноречиво). Простое неосложненное предложение.

(2) *Как всегдА, тонко и красноречИво, описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.* Здесь два наречия относятся к глаголу, причем второе обособленное наречное сочетание имеет значение уточнения.

(3) *Как всегдА, тонко и красноречиво описал свои чувства Владимир Познер.*
Это уже функция вводного слова, сочетание обособляется.

6. Теперь  анализируем **полное высказывание.** Прямая речь значительно распространена и состоит из нескольких предложений. Поэтому слова автора (авторскую характеристику) обособляем не тире, как  здесь предлагалось, а обычным способом – **запятой и тире** (единым знаком), то есть используем  классическое оформление.
7. А вот для авторских слов любое осложнение конструкции (особенно обособление внутри предложения) **нежелательно,** иначе структура всего высказывания не будет прочитываться достаточно ясно. Поэтому выбираем **вариант (1)** без обособления.

Answer (score 0):

Не жалею, не зову, не плачу.
Всё пройдёт, как с белых яблонь дым.
Увяданья золотом охваченный,
Я не буду больше молодым, –
так С. Есенин раскрывает тему вечного потока жизни, тему изменения и обновления.

По-моему, запятая перед тире не нужна, если следовать Розенталю:

Примечания: 1. После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих словах автора содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка обычно начинается словами: так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает и т. п.):

«Ничего не случилось» — так говорил ум; «Случилось» — так говорило сердце; «Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» — так описывает эту местность один путешественник; «Будь внимателен и осторожен!» — вот что он сказал мне на прощание.

Comment: Если  у нас короткая реплика, то можно следовать правилу Розенталя. Но, как известно,  единый знак может заменять простое тире, если у нас не реплика, не одно предложение, а сложная конструкция.  Это как раз область применения единого знака, иначе мы характеристику прямой речи отнесем только к последнему предложению. Поэтому я предлагаю в данном случае не следовать правилу Розенталя.